# Discordjs intents not valid?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
/home/kevind/Downloads/VibeUtils2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:548
      throw new TypeError('CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS');
      ^

TypeError [CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS]: Valid intents must be provided for the Client.
    at Client._validateOptions (/home/kevind/Downloads/VibeUtils2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:548:13)
    at new Client (/home/kevind/Downloads/VibeUtils2/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:76:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kevind/Downloads/VibeUtils2/commands/role.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kevind/Downloads/VibeUtils2/index.js:13:21) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS'
```

This is the error I'm getting, however my code looks like

```
const fs = require('fs');
const {prefix, reactEmoji, token, clientId, guildId} = require('./config/config.json');
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync('./events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
const { Client, Collection, Intents, Discord } = require('discord.js');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_BANS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
client.commands = new Collection();


const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`)
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}


const commands = [];
const slashcommandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./slashcommands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of slashcommandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./slashcommands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), { body: commands })
    .then(() => console.log('Successfully registered application commands.'))
    .catch(console.error);

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, client));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, client));
    }

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('welcome')) {
     message.react(reactEmoji);
     console.log(`Reacted on ${message.author.tag}'s message.`);
    }
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    const command = client.commands.get(commandName) || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

    if (!command) return;

    try {
      command.execute(message, args);
    }catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('There was an error while trying to execute that command!');
    }
    
})};

client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

I'm still handing normal commands until v12 gets deprecated,and so I can transition. However I'm having issues with intents. Please help me on what intents are valid, because those look valid to me. If I'm doing something critically wrong, then please let me know. This is one of my first times actually delving into v13, however as far as I've seen I've done everything correct, that is going off of documentation. If I missed something please let me know, because I think that should work. Most of my ready is handled in an event file.Is there an easy way to add all intents? The ways I've seen here don't work

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your intents are turned on in your Developer Portal.

- Go to https://discord.com/developers/applications
- Click on your application
- Click on the "Bot" section
- Enable the intents you need there; these are only privileged intents so not everything will be there, you will need the Server Members Intent & Message Content Intent (just so you're ready for when it is enforced)

Upon checking,`GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS` and `GUILD_BANS` are not valid intents in Discord.js V12. You'll either need to switch or remove those intents from your array. (Added from comments, just so it's easier to find)

As for adding every intent at once, that's not really possible. Though you could run this in the repl and paste the results into the intents array (this is done in V13, I highly suggest running this yourself in a node repl so it uses your Discord.js version):

```js
const discord = require("discord.js"); const intents = Object.keys(discord.Intents.FLAGS); let formattedIntents = []; intents.forEach((intent) => {formattedIntents.push(`"${intent}"`)}); formattedIntents;
```

(I made this as one-line as possible because I tested it in my bot's eval slash command, but what it does is pretty simple, imports d.js, gets the keys of the `discord.Intents.FLAGS`, makes an empty array to hold them, loops through the intents and pushes it to the array, then outputs the list of intents.)
Which should output

```
"GUILDS","GUILD_MEMBERS","GUILD_BANS","GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS","GUILD_INTEGRATIONS","GUILD_WEBHOOKS","GUILD_INVITES","GUILD_VOICE_STATES","GUILD_PRESENCES","GUILD_MESSAGES","GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS","GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING","DIRECT_MESSAGES","DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS","DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING","GUILD_SCHEDULED_EVENTS"
```

though I'm not sure if you really want or need *every* intent.

Comment: Right, thank you. My intents are enabled on the dev portal. I answered that question before, I guess the OP deleted their post.

Comment: Upon checking Intents in Discord.js V12 (which I believe is the one you're still using) `GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS` and `GUILD_BANS` are invalid and only exist in V13. A full list of V12 intents can be found here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v12/class/Intents